# Open file with started vim from outside (in terminal)

Tags: terminal, vim

I have a started `vim`. I suspended it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>). So I was in terminal session and I would like to open some file with the same `vim` session (new tab). I can open the file in new `vim` session. Actually, path to file could be constructed. **For example**,

```
vim `find $PWD -name build.xml`
```

Is it possible to open this file inside the running vim session from hosting terminal session?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The problem with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>

When you suspend a process with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>, the process gets a `SIGTSTP` signal, and all execution will stop (i.e., no more CPU cycles), until a `SIGCONT` signal comes along. You will not be able to send `vim` any commands or input while it is suspended.

In other words, don't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>.

Yet if you have `vim` compiled with the `clientserver` feature enabled, you can make use of the `--servername` and `--remote-*` options:

### Use `vim --remote`

When starting your `vim` session for the first time, use `vim --servername VIM [filename ...]` (filename is optional if you want to start with a blank session).

Leave it running in your terminal. Now you can control it from any other terminal window, tab, machine, etc., via `vim --remote` commands. To open a file (e.g., **file.txt** in a new tab of your existing `vim` session:

```
vim --remote-tab file.txt
```

To use `vim`'s internal `:tabfind` functionality (see `:help find` for more information):

```
vim --remote-send ":tabfind filename.txt<CR>"
```

To use your system's `find(1)` program instead, as you asked in your question:

```
vim --remote-tab `find $PWD -name build.xml`
```

### Multiple sessions

You can also specify a different `--servername`, which is useful if you want *multiple* vim sessions. In that case, you need to supply the `--servername` argument every time:

```
vim --servername HAMBURGER # Start new session named "HAMBURGER"
vim --servername HAMBURGER --remote-tab `find $PWD -name BACON`
```

Of course you can roll this all into a shell script or two to save yourself some typing.

Answer (score 4):

From within `vim` you can use:

```
:tabe `find $PWD -name build.xml`
```

Answer (score 2):

Though the other answers sound cleaner to me, as a hack, you could use a function like:

```
for-vim () {
  printf %s "$@" > ~/.for-vim &&
    perl -le 'require "sys/ioctl.ph"; ioctl(STDIN, &TIOCSTI, $_)
     for split "", "\e:tabe `cat ~/.for-vim`\r"' &&
    fg %vim
}
```

To be used as:

```
for-vim "$(find "$PWD" ...)"
```

It stores the file path in a `~/.for-vim` file, and injects a `<ESC>:tabe ~/.for-vm<CR>` in the terminal's input buffer using the TIOCSTI ioctl() before resuming `vim`.